# Como "pegar" hora do sistema no Portugol Studio

Tags: biblioteca, portugol, portugol-studio

Eu sei que é preciso importar a biblioteca Calendario.Mas não sei o funcionamento da função hora_atual.Estou tentando imprimir na tela para testar essa funçao.
Vai o seguite código

```
programa{
    inclua biblioteca Calendario
    funcao inicio()
    {
        real valor

        escreva("{Exercício 20 - É possivel assistir o filme?}\n\n")
        escreva("{============ Cinema Estudonauta ===========\n}")
        escreva("Horário do filme: 12h - Preço do ingresso: R$20,00\n")
        escreva("--------------------------------------------------")
        escreva("Quanto dinheiro você tem? R$")
        leia(valor)

        escreva(Calendario.hora_atual(formato_24h))
        }
}
```

Desulpe a formatação do código.Pois ainda não sei formatar por aqui no StackoverFlow.

Obs: Estou usando distro linux.Isso interfere alguma coisa?

Comment: Essa função receber um valor lógico como parâmetro, utiliza ela como Calendario.hora_atual(verdadeiro) ou Calendario.hora_atual(falso)

Comment: Daniel obrigado pela ajuda.Aqui no stackoverflow quando existe um -1 ao lado da pergunta o que significa?

Comment: Que alguém votou de forma negativa, isso pode acontecer tanto na pergunta quanto na resposta.

Comment: Dê uma lida nessa parte aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir resolver o exercício.E ainda aprimorá-lo adicionando minutos do sistema á lógica.O parâmetro da função hora_atual era verdadeiro ou falso.Era aí que estava errando.

```
programa
{
    inclua biblioteca Calendario
    funcao inicio()
    {
        real valor
        inteiro hora , minuto

        escreva("{Exercício 20 - É possivel assistir o filme?}\n\n")
        escreva("{============ Cinema Estudonauta ===========\n}")
        escreva("Horário do filme: 14h - Preço do ingresso: R$20,00\n")
        escreva("--------------------------------------------------\n")
        escreva("Quanto dinheiro você tem? R$")
        leia(valor)

        hora   = Calendario.hora_atual(falso))
        minuto = Calendario.minuto_atual()

        se(hora <= 14 e minuto < 1 e valor >=20 ){
            escreva("Agora são "+hora+":"+minuto+".Você consegue comprar o ingresso!")  
        }senao{
            escreva("Agora são "+hora+":"+minuto+". Infelizmente não é possível comprar os ingresso !")
        }

    }
}
```